# Hook to get details of taxonomy term page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I wrote a module to store taxonomy page details to DB. My requirement is to store `tid`, `term name`, `vid` and UNIX `timestamp` to DB table on every load of taxonomy term page. Here is my code:

```
function reporting_api_taxonomy_term_load($terms) {
  $tid = $terms[arg(2)]->tid;
  $vid = $terms[arg(2)]->vid;
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
  $name = $term->name;
  db_insert('reporting_api')
    ->fields(array(
      'tid' => $tid,
      'name' => $name,
      'vid' => $vid,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

But it creates unwanted rows with timestamp only. Can any one help to fix this. Is `hook_taxonomy_term_load` is the correct hook.

Comment: You may use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_view/7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy terms can also be loaded when you're not on a taxonomy page, so `arg(2)` will be empty, hence empty records.

To fix:

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
if ($term) {
  db_insert('reporting_api')
    ->fields(array(
      'tid' => $term->tid,
      'name' => $term->name,
      'vid' => $term->vid,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks clive. I tried the modified code. But `<?php
function custom_rep_taxonomy_term_load($terms) {
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($term); exit;` giving error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /includes/database/log.inc on line 0`. I am using D7 with oracle.

Comment: i rewrite my code. 
`function custom_rep_taxonomy_term_view($term, $view_mode, $langcode) {

if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2)) ) {

$terms = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
  
  db_insert('custom_rep')
    ->fields(array(
      'tid' => $terms->tid,
      'name' => $terms->name,
      'vid' => $terms->vid,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
 }
}` Works fine